# JavaFx displaying info when a thread is terminated

Tags: javafx

Here is my code in a loop I display the value of I in a label

```
   private void doLongOperation() throws InterruptedException {
        for (int i=1;i<=10;i++){
            System.out.println(i);
            Thread.sleep(500);
            int finalI = i;
            Platform.runLater(()->
            {
                monLabel.setText("Value From thread : "+ finalI);
                monBouton.setText("counting ..."+finalI);
            });
        }
    }
```

I call this function on a thread :

```
  Thread t11= new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            doLongOperation();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
 t11.start();
```

It works but I'd like to set my button text to "Something ..." when the thread is terminated, how can I implement this ?
I've tried `if(t11.getState()== Thread.State.TERMINATED)` but it's never terminated, I've tried `t11.Join()` but it no longer update the UI ??
Thanks for your help

I also try

```
finally {
/*                monBouton.setText("Do long operation");
                monBouton.disableProperty().set(false);*/
            }
```

But it tells me it's not a javas thread ...

Comment: Why not simply add another `Platform.runLater` after the loop or in the `finally`?

Comment: Thanks you're right             }finally {
                Platform.runLater(()->{
                    monBouton.setText("Do long operation");
                    monBouton.disableProperty().set(false);
                });

            }
        });

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Fabian

```
    }finally {
        Platform.runLater(()->{
            monBouton.setText("Do long operation");
            monBouton.disableProperty().set(false);
        });

    }
});
```